# App crash when cable disconnected from Mac

Tags: swift2, xcode7

this app is running normally on simulator, is running normally while attached in my Mac, but when disconnected it crashes.
There are other very old posts in StackOverflow, but even that I tried to follow did not work as well. What I did till now was:
1-To stop Xcode first and after disconnect the cable does not work.
2-To Stop the app first and after disconnect the iPhone does not work, the app does not run in the iPhone
3-Delete the app from the iPhone and run it again
4-Product Clean in Xcode 
I have no debug because the app is disconnected from Xcode. Anyone knows what it is?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go to Xcode -> Windows -> Devices. Select your device and there you can see some logs and also all the Crash Logs of your apps.

Maybe those logs can help you. Also you should paste the logs in your question and the chances to get help are higher.

Comment: Thank you, I will add the log but it is long :(

Comment: The log is more than 40.000 characters, how can I post it? I can not read these logs :(

Answer (score 2):

I got the same problem. It turned out that I had some checkboxes checked in

Product->Scheme->Edit scheme->Run->Diagnostics.

After I unchecked them the app started working after being installed and disconnected from Mac.