# App wont run once disconnected from Xcode

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, crash, xcode10.1

My app runs all fine when it is connected to Xcode. (I am using Xcode 10.1)
But as soon as i disconnect the device and launch the app again (by tapping on icon) splash screen appears and the app closes. This is not an actual crash because the app works fine when connected with wire. I also have Crashlytics integrated in my app and there are no crashes on it's dashboard too.

Things I have tried:

1. Clean and build the code.
2. Restart the device.
3. Go to window -> devices and simulators and tried to check device
   logs (as [App crash when cable disconnected from Mac](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33554219/app-crash-when-cable-disconnected-from-mac) suggests) but I did not find anything there.

Here are the logs:

> Date/Time:       2018-12-07 12:36:24 +0500 End time:        2018-12-07
>   12:36:26 +0500 OS Version:      iPhone OS 12.0.1 (Build 16A404)
>   Architecture:    arm64 Report Version:  27 Incident Identifier:
>   4DAE256F-7C3C-4CF5-A670-BD0FA2498CA5
>
> Data Source:     Microstackshots Shared Cache:    0x8fe0000
>   5D8B6846-4668-3CAC-9CC4-4A762D54BE9E
>
> Command:         Cuufy Path:
>   /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/EDAA1D65-BB6F-4722-8619-FDFED10DC045/Cuufy.app/Cuufy
>   Identifier:      com.cuufyLLC.cuufy Version:         1.3 (1) Beta
>   Identifier: A032A60E-406C-442D-836A-80540F61ADCA PID:             2478
>
> Event:           wakeups Action taken:    none Wakeups:         45001
>   wakeups over the last 141 seconds (318 wakeups per second average),
>   exceeding limit of 150 wakeups per second over 300 seconds Wakeups
>   limit:   45000 Limit duration:  300s Wakeups caused:  45001 Duration: 
>   1.99s Steps:           3
>
> Hardware model:  iPhone9,1 Active cpus:     2 Boot args:
>
> Heaviest stack for the target process:   3  ???
>   (libsystem_pthread.dylib + 49392) [0x189ad20f0]   3  ???
>   (libdispatch.dylib + 73472) [0x1898a0f00]   3  ??? (libdispatch.dylib
>   + 38752) [0x189898760]   3  ??? (libdispatch.dylib + 35864) [0x189897c18]   3  ??? (libdispatch.dylib + 398468) [0x1898f0484]   3 
>   ??? (libdispatch.dylib + 394952) [0x1898ef6c8]   3  ???
>   (<38F5549F-536E-3252-B54B-8CA43AD79EB0> + 59736) [0x101a6e958]   2 
>   ??? (<38F5549F-536E-3252-B54B-8CA43AD79EB0> + 61980) [0x101a6f21c]   2
>   ??? (libsystem_c.dylib + 480420) [0x1899c24a4]   1  ???
>   (libsystem_kernel.dylib + 144424) [0x189a4d428]
>
> Powerstats for:  Cuufy [2478] UUID:
>   907E938F-A407-382A-BFE9-BB62948993A1 Path:
>   /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/EDAA1D65-BB6F-4722-8619-FDFED10DC045/Cuufy.app/Cuufy
>   Architecture:    arm64 Parent:          UNKNOWN [1] UID:
>   501 Footprint:       202.73 MB Start time:      2018-12-07 12:36:24
>   +0500 End time:        2018-12-07 12:36:26 +0500 Num samples:     3 (100%) CPU Time:        1.501s Primary state:   2 samples Frontmost
>   App, Non-Suppressed, User mode, Effective Thread QoS User Initiated,
>   Requested Thread QoS User Initiated, Override Thread QoS Unspecified
>   User Activity:   0 samples Idle, 0 samples Active, 3 samples Unknown
>   Power Source:    0 samples on Battery, 0 samples on AC, 3 samples
>   Unknown   3  _pthread_wqthread + 311 (libsystem_pthread.dylib + 49392)
>   [0x189ad20f0]
>       3  _dispatch_workloop_worker_thread + 599 (libdispatch.dylib + 73472) [0x1898a0f00]
>         3  _dispatch_lane_invoke$VARIANT$mp + 431 (libdispatch.dylib + 38752) [0x189898760]
>           3  _dispatch_lane_serial_drain$VARIANT$mp + 591 (libdispatch.dylib + 35864) [0x189897c18]
>             3  _dispatch_client_callout + 15 (libdispatch.dylib + 398468) [0x1898f0484]
>               3  _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 23 (libdispatch.dylib + 394952) [0x1898ef6c8]
>                 3  thunk for @escaping @callee_guaranteed -> () (WebSocket.swift:0) (WebSocket.swift:0 in Starscream + 59736)
>   [0x101a6e958]
>                   2  closure #1 in FoundationStream.connect (WebSocket.swift:209) (WebSocket.swift:209 in Starscream + 61980)
>   [0x101a6f21c]
>                     2  usleep + 63 (libsystem_c.dylib + 480420) [0x1899c24a4]
>                       1  __semwait_signal + 8 (libsystem_kernel.dylib + 144424) [0x189a4d428]
>                         1  
>                       1  nanosleep + 211 (libsystem_c.dylib + 480720) [0x1899c25d0]
>                         1  __semwait_signal + 23 (libsystem_kernel.dylib + 144440) [0x189a4d438]
>                           1  _pthread_exit_if_canceled + 0 (libsystem_pthread.dylib + 52556) [0x189ad2d4c]
>                   1  closure #1 in FoundationStream.connect (WebSocket.swift:216) (WebSocket.swift:216 in Starscream + 62020)
>   [0x101a6f244]
>                     1  CFWriteStreamCopyError + 0 (CoreFoundation + 772364) [0x189e5690c]
>
> Binary Images:
>              0x100524000 -                ???  Cuufy                   <907E938F-A407-382A-BFE9-BB62948993A1> 
>   /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/EDAA1D65-BB6F-4722-8619-FDFED10DC045/Cuufy.app/Cuufy
>              0x101a60000 -                ???  ???                     <38F5549F-536E-3252-B54B-8CA43AD79EB0>  Starscream
>              0x18988f000 -        0x1898fffff  libdispatch.dylib        
>   /usr/lib/system/libdispatch.dylib
>              0x18994d000 -        0x1899cbfff  libsystem_c.dylib       <40DD5C3B-586A-38EB-9F52-74D994ECD9D2> 
>   /usr/lib/system/libsystem_c.dylib
>              0x189a2a000 -        0x189a54fff  libsystem_kernel.dylib  <982CCBAD-717D-3A28-946E-BA07918897A3> 
>   /usr/lib/system/libsystem_kernel.dylib
>              0x189ac6000 -        0x189ad6fff  libsystem_pthread.dylib  
>   /usr/lib/system/libsystem_pthread.dylib
>              0x189d9a000 -        0x18a0fffff  CoreFoundation           
>   /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/CoreFoundation

Comment: what's your device log

Comment: @SPatel I have updated the question. Please check.

Comment: @kinza Are you doing any heavy works in the Appdelegate or your view lifecycle methods ?

Comment: @MidhunMP No :(
Just posting some local notifications.

Comment: @kinza: Could you please comment out that local notification posting and check whether this issue still there or not, also are you using dispatch_queues or NSThread in any of the places which can affect the initial loading ?

Comment: try to build the app on the device , disconnect the cable then launch it on the device, PS don't launch the app while connected

Comment: @MidhunMP No I have not used NSThread or dispatch queue. I have also comment the code from app delegate. Still no effect :(

Comment: @7bebMrto No effect..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my code in splash screen I was trying to access environment variable of the scheme set on the basis of which I was setting some views. Those variables were accessible when the device was connected with wire but returning nil when device was not connected (I would appreciate if anyone clears the reason for this)
So to solve this I deleted the schemes and created targets instead, set custom flags (to base the work i was previously doing with environment variables) and then accessed them as described in second answer of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24003291/ifdef-replacement-in-the-swift-language) question.

Answer (score 0):

I think this has something to do with the usage of the Starscream Websocket library and/or the network connectivity of the device.

While the device is running in the simulator, it uses the network connection of your Mac(Book/Pro/etc.); when it is running on it's own, it uses the wifi/cellular connection of the device.

Therefore, I think you'll just face some high latancy due to the devices connectivity.

- Check the network connectivity
- Try to disable (comment) the Starscrem usages and check if the application is starting
- Check if the UI is waiting for network data before displaying anything